# Creating User Profiles using author.php

Tags: users, author, profiles

I am trying to create a user profile template using author.php. However, the template remains blank if I try to see the profile of a user that has not created any posts.

www.website.com/author/user1 -> Has written Posts -> Template shows User info

www.website.com/author/user2 -> Subscriber account -> template remains empty

How can I tell Wordpress to fill in the information for every user?

Edit: My Code so far:

```
<?php
get_header();
$userID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
$user = get_userdata($userID);
?>


<div class="profile-wrapper">

    <div class="row justify-content-center user-info">
        <div class="col-lg-5 text-center">
            <span><?php echo get_avatar($user->ID, 150) ?></span>
            <h2 class="heading-semibig"><?php echo $user->display_name ?></h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the code in the template? Are you trying to output the user information after `if ( have_posts() ) :`?

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't have any if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )` gets the ID of the author of the current post. If there's no post there's no author.

Use `get_queried_object_id()` instead. When used on author archives (i.e. author.php) it will be the ID of the author, regardless of whether or not they have posts.